# php boolean's lower AND upper case and numerical boolean's acceptable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, boolean

I have this line of code in PHP:

```
if($connect->query("INSERT INTO users (last_login) VALUES ('$now')") === TRUE) ...
```

and this line.

```
return true;
```

I've noticed that PHP booleans are sometimes uppercase and sometimes lowercase.

Why is this?

Should I use one for better performance?

Do they produce different results?

If so, what is the difference?

Are numeric booleans acceptable in PHP, because in JavaScript, booleans can be 0 and 1.

IE in JavaScript, you can do:

```
if(0) ... // false

if(1) ... // true
```

Comment: they're the same. `To specify a boolean literal, use the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.` FIG-3 standards recomends using lowercase as standard, but that's up to you

Comment: What does FIG-3 stand for / mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant PSR, FIG is the overall name. And it's PSR-2, not 3, but anyway: head [here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2) for all the info you need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a truth value *manually* by stating that with the identity operator =.

```
$var = TRUE; // or true, is the same.
```

Anyway, boolean values are assigned automatically according to the nature of the variable you are considering. For example, a numeric value will be FALSE if it is 0, or TRUE in the other cases. A string will be FALSE just if empty.

Comment: Glad that I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's rules on type-looseness and boolean conversions are fairly complex. From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) (and Damien's comment): `To specify a boolean literal, use the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.`

Further down the page, under the "Converting to boolean" heading, all of the rules of numeric booleans, string booleans, etc. I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with them to avoid unintentional behavior. To answer your question directly: yes, numeric booleans are supported. And empty strings. And the string `"0"` will also count as `false`.